# Using SharePoint to hold a Leaderboard for a game

Tags: database

We are creating a very simple game (Flash based) that we wish to host in a SharePoint environment.

We want to get score details from the Game to display a Leaderboard of high scores within the SharePoint environment - without the user having to go into the game.

How can this be done?

Comment: Depends totally on whether/how the game saves scores outside of itself. Does it save scores to a text file, for example? Or a database somewhere? If so, SharePoint can take these scores and display them on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make ActionScript call the SharePoint REST endpoints.

Provided you embed the SWF file directly in a SharePoint ASPX page, if you embed in an IFRAME you can't get out of the container.